# How to fix getting an HTTP status code of 0 with TWSocket component using Delphi 6?

Tags: delphi, http, sockets, httpclient

I have an application written in Delphi 6 that uses the THttpCli component, a client that acts as an HTTP client and uses an ICS TWSocket internally to manage the request.  I am having a weird problem with using it that seems to be related to a timing problem.  I have included the relevant block of code from the component below, the code where after the web document request is made (an HTTP POST request), the underlying TWSocket control loops while waiting for a response from the server.

If I let the code run uninterrupted, I invariably get an HTTP status code of 0 returned by the operation with an empty result document.  However, if I step through the wait loop then after 3 iterations I invariably get a successful response.  The following is sheer speculation on my part, but it is almost as if the code is reacting too quickly to the incoming response from the web server and is making a premature judgement as to when it has actually received a response.  Therefore, making an incorrect judgement that does not occur if I single step through the loop thereby introducing a wait period between checks of the O/S level socket by the TWSocket code.

The web server I am interacting with is actually a WiFi connected device on my local router, in other words, a network peer.  I am wondering if perhaps the TWSocket code was written in a way that did not expect to get a response back that quickly?  What contradicts this is that I have used that very component with other peer programs acting as a web server on the same PC and did not get a problem.  Perhaps the web server in this failing case is returning things in an unexpected progressive manner?  I have tried executing the web request with Chrome and other browsers on my system and they handle the query without any trouble at all.

If anyone has any ideas on what could be the root cause and how to fix it, please let me know.  I am trying to avoid a massive bug hunt through pages of socket related code.

```
procedure THttpCli.DoRequestSync(Rq : THttpRequest);
var
    DummyHandle     : THandle;
begin
    DoRequestAsync(Rq);

{$IFDEF DELPHI1}
    { Delphi 1 has no support for multi-threading }
    while FState <> httpReady do
        Application.ProcessMessages;
{$ELSE}
    if FMultiThreaded then begin
        while FState <> httpReady do begin
            FCtrlSocket.ProcessMessages;
            Sleep(0);
        end;
    end
    else begin
        while FState <> httpReady do begin
            { Do not use 100% CPU }
            DummyHandle := INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
            MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(0, DummyHandle, FALSE, 1000,
                                      QS_ALLINPUT + QS_ALLEVENTS +
                                      QS_KEY + QS_MOUSE);
{$IFNDEF NOFORMS}
            Application.ProcessMessages;
            if Application.Terminated then begin
                Abort;
                break;
            end;
{$ELSE}
            FCtrlSocket.ProcessMessages;
{$ENDIF}
        end;
    end;
{$ENDIF}

{* Jul 12, 2004
   WARNING: The component now doesn't consider 401 status
            as a fatal error (no exception is triggered). This required a
            change in the application code if it was using the exception that
            is no more triggered for status 401 and 407.
*}
    {* if FStatusCode > 401 then    Dec 14, 2004 *}
    if (FStatusCode >= 400) and (FStatusCode <> 401) and (FStatusCode <> 407) then
        raise EHttpEx
end;
```

**UPDATE**: The problem appears to be something related to THttpCli trying to do automatic logins.  THttpCli has a user name and password pair of properties that you can use, if I am correct, to have it automatically try to login if the server returns a 401 error (authorization failure).  I discovered this by tracing through the component code.  I found that there was a 401 response coming back that was being swallowed (not reported) by the component.  It looks like the status code of 0 happens during the retry attempt with login details and that masks the 401 response.

I got around the problem by adding the needed authentication line manually to the request headers using the OnBeforeHeaderSend() event fired by THttpCli.  That event is fired right before the web request is made and is designed specifically for that purpose (to allow you to modify the request headers).  This short circuits the need for the component to do an automatic login so it is a workaround but not a direct solution to the problem.  If anyone knows a direct solution please let me know.

Comment: which state is it before the first line - DoRequestAsync(Rq); - is invoked? Maybe httpReady is the default value and the async request has not yet done anything, but returns control immediatilay to the DoRequestSync method? (But to solve the whole problem of emulating blocking socket operations, I would redesign the code - iirc ICS supports blocking sockets)

Comment: @mjn.  See my latest update to the post please.